# How to specify/override geolocation in capybara and phantomjs

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, phantomjs, capybara

I want to set my geolocation before visiting a site. How can I do that?

A small example script is as follows:

```
Capybara.default_driver = :poltergeist
driver_name = "poltergeist_#{rand 1_000_000}"
Capybara.run_server     = false
Capybara.current_driver = driver_name
Capybara.default_wait_time = 10
opts = {}
Capybara.register_driver driver_name do |app|
  opts = { :js_errors => true, :phantomjs_options => ['--ignore-ssl-errors=yes', '--ssl-protocol=TLSv1'], :timeout => 90 }
  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new app, opts
end
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/537.13+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.7 Safari/534.57.2'
Capybara.current_session.driver.headers = { 'User-Agent' => user_agent}
Capybara
browser = Capybara
# now my attempt to set geolocation, which is unsuccessful.
  browser.page.execute_script "navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition = function(success, failure) { success({coords: {latitude: 25.455755, longitude: -80.511565}, timestamp: Date.now()}); }"
```

but if i now head to a location-aware site, i dont see data relevant to my geolocation. So overriding geolocation fails.

what is the correct way to set geolocation?

Comment: Are you certain that the site in question uses the clientside JS `geolocation` api to get the user's geolocation? 
One way to check is to throw an `alert` or `console.log` into your `getCurrentPosition` function and see if it really is called.
I for one tend to use ip address lookups on the server side for geolocation, so this method wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this with execute_script will be executed after your page has loaded (and usually already checked whether the browser supports geolocation) which makes it non-useful.  Instead you want to use the extension ability of Poltergeist/PhantomJS to mock geolocation.  Here's a good post explaining how to do this - http://collectiveidea.com/blog/archives/2014/01/21/mocking-html5-apis-using-phantomjs-extensions

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will read it up and if it solves my problem, can accept ur answer if it is still the best answer :).